# Codeigniter Session data lost on the third navigation

Tags: codeigniter, session, configuration, settings

This is a really strange problem. I have an application that I build using Codeigniter 3, HMVC, and Ion Auth. It was working well until I migrated it from one server to another. Now the data in the session is cleared after 3 navigations.

I tested it by logging into the application and watching the data field in the  ci_session table as I navigated. I made it as simple as possible. I perform a browser refresh from the view I reach after login. On the third refresh, the data disappears from the database for my session and the application sends me back to the login page (application checks to see if the user is logged in). I even waited awhile (less than the 7200) to see if it was a time out and the time between refreshes does not seem to matter. I did not add code, because I do not know what code would help.

Does anyone have an idea what setting may be the cause?

Comment: Codeigniter 3 session is stored in files not in db

Answer (score 0):

Some time `Codeigniter` Session not working it has problem with `PHP` version
Change Your Server `PHP` Version.